# How to imitate return type DeleteResult of mongodb for mocking?

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

Im using mockito, and one of the mock is of service that have a method with return type `Future[DeleteResult]`, and in my test i have something like:

```
val myService = mock[MyService]

when(myService.doSomething(5)) thenReturn Future.successful(???)
```

but i dont know how to imitate `DeleteResult`...

Comment: Instantiate a delete result and return it in the `Future.successful(???)` http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/result/DeleteResult.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple you can initiate it like so:

```
import com.mongodb.client.result.DeleteResult
DeleteResult.acknowledged(1)
```